# Пустое значение переменной

Tags: c++

Как определить, пуста ли переменная, к примеру, типа `int`?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под выражением "пуста"? Она не инициализировалась ничем в явном виде (в духе `int a;`)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 15):

Переменные встроенных типов (`int`, `double` и т. д.) не могут быть пустыми в принципе, даже если вы их не инициализировали. В любом случае переменная будет иметь какое-либо значение.

При объявлении переменной (например, `int a;`) ей выделяется память, если переменную не инициализировать, то значение переменной будет равно тому мусору, который был в памяти до этого. Поэтому пуста ли переменная спрашивать некорректно, и так же считается хорошим правилом всегда инициализировать переменные значением при объявлении.

Answer (score 14):

Используйте `optional<T>` (например Boost.Optional), тогда у переменной будет специальное пустое значение.

Comment: Теперь этот тип есть и в стандартной библиотеке.

Answer (score 14):

Никак.

Переменная целого типа может быть неинициализирована, и попытка чтения из неё есть ошибка согласно стандарту (так называемое «неопределённое поведение»). После этой ошибки ничего более не гарантировано. Так что вы не можете просто «проверить значение».

Логика «ну какое-то значение ведь там будет, раз память выделена» неверна, стандарт этого не гарантирует. Наоборот, после такой проверки все остальные гарантии отменяются.

Вы не можете проверить переменную локально. Вы должны сами убедиться в том, что все переменные правильно инициализированы. Компилятор C++ ничего не сделает за вас, он считает вас очень взрослым и очень ответственным. (В отличие от других языков, которые контролируют вас более плотно.)

Comment: Кстати, для типа `unsigned char` UB не возникает при использовании неопределенного (неинициализированного) значения. См. `ISO/IEC 14882:2014 8.5/12.`

Comment: @alexolut: Исходя из текста, не «_не возникает_», а «_не всегда возникает_». Там есть прекрасный поясняющий пример.

Answer (score 10):

Нельзя никак определить инициализирована ли переменная фундаментального типа или нет. Т.к. отсутствие инициализации подразумевает (в частном случае) наличие любого случайного (мусорного) значения.

При этом компилятор в отладочном режиме всё же может писать в такие переменные какое-то определенное значение (в том числе и ноль), по которому можно косвенно понять, что переменная не была инициализирована. Косвенно, потому, что вполне возможно инициализировать переменную явно точно таким же значением.

Дополнительно, при отсутствии инициализации, компилятор также может сообщить об этом соответствующим предупреждением, если попытаться использовать значение неинициализированной переменной.

Comment: Причем на эти предупреждения нельзя полагаться, например такой код: `int a; bool b = false; if (b) a = 0; a++;` может не выдать никаких предупреждений.

Comment: @andy.37 clang кстати [умеет](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EvwOWfRlt4t7H7H6). Но вообще, наличие такой диагностики не является обязательным по Стандарту, поэтому я и написал, что `может сообщить`, но не обязан.

Comment: по той же причине я написал "*может* не выдать". Наверное, следовало написать "не следует полагаться на отсутствие предупреждений такого рода". В общем, консенсус))) П.С. Куда написать вопрос по работе собственно сайта ruSO?

Comment: @andy.37 тут есть мета секция на сайте. Туда и писать.

Answer (score 1):

Тип **int** может предоставить 2^32 = 4*10^9 различный объектов.

```
ObjInt = { obj1 , obj2 , ... , obj4294967296 }
```

При старте функции в стеке эта переменная может быть инициализирована неопределёнными значениями. От obj1 до obj4294967296. Если у вас объектов меньше *(например 1000)* то можно выбрать состояние obj4294967296 и его назвать *пусто*. Но всё равно всем объектам нужно назначить это состояние.

```
int i , j ;
i = -1 ; // пусто
j = 5 ;
```

Другой вариант если состояний будет максимум 4294967296. Тогда 4294967296+1=4294967297 состояний не будет вмещаться в **int** физически. Исправить это можно очень многими способами. Например дополнительной переменной, означающим этот признак пустоты. И опять при старте функции этот признак пустоты будет заполнен случайным (неопределённым) значением. Его нужно выставить сразу.

```
bool ie = true ;
bool je = true ;
int i , j ;
i = -1 ; ie = false ;
j = 5 ; je = false ;
```