# Переменная = empty

Tags: c++, инициализация, объявление

Можно ли в c++ новосозданной переменной присвоить значение empty?

Comment: можно. примерно так `clazz *a = null`

Comment: Это, конечно, можно, но скорее всего вам это _не нужно_. В подавляющем большинстве случаев вам известно хорошее, логичное начальное значение для переменной.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495895/176217

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++ 17 имеется класс `std::optional` - обертка вокруг других объектов, который позволяет определять, есть ли значение у переменной или нет.

Однако многие компиляторы еще не поддерживают этот класс.

Поэтому для фундаментальных типов нет такого значения, как empty. Вы можете переменные этих типов инициализировать нулем, как это делает компилятор для статических переменных. Тем не менее нельзя сказать, что такие значения являются значением empty.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответу выше, имеется еще `boost::optional` и `boost::tribool`.
Простенькая реализация аналога `optional` пилится самостоятельно очень быстро.